# Migrating existing Music to Spotify?

Tags: spotify

I have a huge folder of music (I don't have iTunes), and I recently got Spotify Premium. I want to match all my local music on Spotify library, removing the local files and only saving those that don't exist on Spotify. Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score -1):

A bit of quick googing shows a few apps:

- http://www.ivyishere.org/
- http://www.getunify.com/